# mysql refusing network connection

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying us ems as a frontend to administer my databases's. However, I have tried as a host: IP, DOMAIN, TUNNELING, SSH TUNNELING, HTTP TUNNELING, but all I keep getting is 'network is refusing your connection (10061). I think I may have found out why but am not experienced enough to make the changes.

I have included values for mysql from my php info file below:

```
mysql.default_host  no value    no value
mysql.default_password  no value    no value
mysql.default_port  no value    no value
mysql.default_socket    /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock   /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
mysql.default_user  no value    no value
mysql.max_links Unlimited   Unlimited
```

I would be grateful if someone could cast an eye over this code and inform me if that is the reason for the non connection.

Many thanks

Comment: Can you append an example on how you are trying to connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this documentation: scroll down to your error number.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html

Make sure the MySQL daemon is running.  If it's not, start it.  If it is, make sure you can ping the server and then log in using a client like the mysqladmin tool.  If it can't connect, you won't be able to, either.